# To Build Recursive Query for assembly part numbers having multiple levels in the database

Tags: recursion, google-bigquery

I have the database of Assembly part number. I'm trying to find the heirarchical tree structure for the assembly part numbers. There are 3 important features as - "comp_partno" , "assy_partno" & "na_partno".

1. "comp_partno" is the parent of the dataset
2. "assy_partno" is the child parts with levels inside the same column
3. "na_partno" is the final assembly or end of the structure.
   I scripted the query in GCP Big Query but not receiving the output which I expected.
   We filtered the dataset first by "comp_partno" value then "assy_partno" column is retrieve in first iteration.Now for the next iteration we need to take the first "assy_partno" to fetch the levels which are present inside "assy_partno" ; second  "assy_partno" to fetch the levels and so on ....
   Attaching the dataset on which I'm working.

**[Assembly Part Number : csv format]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC8vN.png)

```
WITH RECURSIVE ParentCTE AS (
  SELECT TRIM(comp_partno) AS comp_partno, TRIM(na_partno) AS na_partno
  FROM ford-e4ca0d3521878034363b85d8.dscdb_pwrsada_test_part_num.Assembly_part_num 
  WHERE TRIM(comp_partno) = '9G866  EU5ABD'
),

RecursiveCTE AS (  
  SELECT TRIM(comp_partno) AS comp_partno, TRIM(assy_partno) AS assy_partno
  FROM ford-e4ca0d3521878034363b85d8.dscdb_pwrsada_test_part_num.Assembly_part_num 
  WHERE TRIM(comp_partno) = '9G866  EU5ABD'    
  
  UNION ALL    

  SELECT TRIM(r.comp_partno) AS comp_partno, TRIM(t.assy_partno) AS assy_partno
  FROM ford-e4ca0d3521878034363b85d8.dscdb_pwrsada_test_part_num.Assembly_part_num  t
  JOIN RecursiveCTE r ON r.assy_partno = t.comp_partno
)

SELECT DISTINCT ParentCTE.comp_partno, ParentCTE.na_partno, RecursiveCTE.assy_partno
FROM RecursiveCTE
JOIN ParentCTE ON RecursiveCTE.comp_partno = ParentCTE.comp_partno
ORDER BY ParentCTE.na_partno;
```

Attaching the output of this query-
[**Output of the above query**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzxrk.png)
I tried this Big query but not getting the output which I'm expecting. I'm expecting that for next iteration it should take the "assy_partno" as next level to fetch the level from "assy_partno" column itself.